# filter product for each year (2013, 2014)

Tags: r

I have following dataset and would like to filter using date, can i use any package ? 
question:Show bestselling and worst selling product for each year (2013, 2014)

```
Date_purchased  Product_name
 9-Jan-13          a
 12-Jan-13         a
 12-Jan-13         b
 1-Feb-13          b
 7-Feb-13          b
 16-Dec-14         a
 16-Dec-14         a
 19-Dec-14         a
 22-Dec-14         c
 1-Jan-15          a
 5-Jan-15          b
 17-Jan-15         c
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: For highest selling

Date_purchased     Product_name

2013                       b

2014                       a

Comment: For 2015, there is tie between all the products based on the example.  So, which one you want to select?

Comment: I just want for 2013 and 2014 but not 2015

Comment: Appreciate your help for a newbie like me in R, getting used to stackoverflow posts

Comment: No problem.  We were all newbies at one time.  You will get used to this pretty soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Best selling product, we could try.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(year= format(as.Date(Date_purchased, '%d-%b-%y'), '%Y'), 
                  Product_name) %>%
   filter(year %in% 2013:2014) %>% 
   mutate(N= n())  %>% 
   group_by(year) %>%
   summarise(Product_name = Product_name[which.max(N)])
 #    year Product_name
 #1 2013            b
 #2 2014            a
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Date_purchased = c("9-Jan-13", "12-Jan-13",
 "12-Jan-13", 
 "1-Feb-13", "7-Feb-13", "16-Dec-14", "16-Dec-14", "19-Dec-14", 
 "22-Dec-14", "1-Jan-15", "5-Jan-15", "17-Jan-15"),
 Product_name = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", 
 "b", "c")), .Names = c("Date_purchased", "Product_name"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

**NOTE:** Replace `which.max` with `which.min` for the worst selling product.

Comment: Thank you Arkun, can you suggest me a link where I can refer more of it. I actually get an error with the above code Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  group_by(year) %>%

Comment: @saket I added the dput of the `df1` dataset.  Can you try the code using that dataset?  I am using  `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`, couldn't get any errors

Comment: @saket You can check this link http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html